# C# Get ApplicationName in Async Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to get the ApplicationName or the AssemblyName in an async Thread

The code is in Class Library Project used by ASP.Net Web Applications and Windows console or Windows Form Application.

When method is called by not async Thread i use

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

for Windows console and Windows Form

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType().BaseType
```

for ASP.Net Web Application.

When method is called in async Thread it's not work because both method return null.

I cant pass a parameter to every thread becouse i cant access to the source code

Comment: You cant use `HttpContext` inside threads because is null, can you post full code, plase?

Comment: @Dani That's my problem, both method return null inside the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find any way to solve my problem, at the moment i do a simple trick.

My method is called before by the main thread and only in the second moment by the async thread. When it's called by Main Thread i store the ApplicationName in a static variable and i use it in async method if i got null in any other methods